# I want to import one package into other in my project directory

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

My project structure is:

```
     project
     |--main
     |   |--__init_.py
     |   |-- file_to_be_imported.py
     |--tests
         |--conftest.py
```

i want to import file_to_be imported into conftest in tests.

"The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the replacement is intended." [from The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

So I read this document and used:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
```

This code in conftest. It's working fine. But is there any other way without using above code snippet?

Comment: I think you can do `from ..main import file_to_be_imported`.

Comment: How do you run your code? conftest is usually run as part of a test framework that does its own import trickery.

Comment: if i tried as you suggested. it's showing `attempted relative import with no known parent package` @nog64

Comment: I am running tests folder using pytest.@MisterMiyagi

Comment: @digamberKALIVEMULA Okay I guess you can't do the `..main` import in this case then. Another solution is to use the `add2virtualenv` command provided by `virtualenvwrapper` if you're using that.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use that code. All you need to do is add `__init__.py` in you **tests** directory.
Your project will look like this :

```
 project
 |--main
 |   |--__init__.py
 |   |-- file_to_be_imported.py
 |--tests
     |--__init__.py
     |--conftest.py
```

And in conftest.py you just import code from main

```
from main import file_to_be_imported
#Write test
```

EDIT:
And then you execute your file like a module not like a regular python file

```
python -m test.conftest
```

If you want to execute it like a regular python file the sys.path is needed.

Comment: Why would that work? `project` still isn't in `sys.path`. I just tried this and as expected it didn't work; still getting `ImportError: No module named 'main'`.

Comment: Actually `__init__.py` helps python discover the files inside your project folder. So you should run your test when you're inside `project`.
Can you comment here your `pytest` command ?

Comment: I was not using `pytest` but I *was* running it from `project`. But just to see, I just installed `pytest` and ran the command `pytest` from `project` and it's still the same error. Just running it from `project` doesn't add `project` to `sys.path`.

Comment: Import `sys` from `os`

```from os import sys, path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))```

Comment: @BeeSheepRocks No, the old import of `sys` worked fine, even without `tests/__init__.py`. The asker wanted to know how to accomplish the import *without* manually modifying `sys.path` in the code. The error I was getting was when I removed that line.

Comment: Thanks @nog642 for your thoughtful remarks. Most of the time, python code uses a main file outside so there's no issue to import subfolder modules. But when you're inside a module and want to execute file from other module, you actually need to add things to path or execute the code as a module.